# find folders in a directory, without listing the parent directory

Tags: linux, bash, find

Having trouble listing the contents of a folder I'm not in, while excluding the actual folder name itself.

ex:

```
root@vps [~]# find ~/test -type d
/root/test
/root/test/test1
```

However I want it to only display /test1, as the example.

Thoughts?

Comment: how about `(cd ~/test && find *)`

Comment: the same question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/153770/how-to-have-find-not-return-the-current-directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with `-exec` and `basename`:

```
find ~/test -type d -exec basename {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

- The `find ~/test -type d` part finds all directories recursively under `~/test`, as you already know.
- The `-exec basename {} \;` part runs the `basename` command on `{}`, which is where all the results from the last step are substituted into.

Comment: I think the OP wants test2/test3, not test3 in case of nested directories. But I'm not sure ;-)

Comment: instead of xargs, replace `\;` with `+`

Answer (score 41):

There's nothing wrong with a simple

```
find ~/test -mindepth 1
```

Similarly, this will have the same effect:

```
find ~/test/*
```

as it matches everything contained within `~/test/` but not `~/test` itself.

As an aside, you'll almost certainly find that `find` will complain about the `-mindepth n` option being after any other switches, as ordering is normally important but the `-(min|max)depth n` switches affect overall behaviour.

Comment: also you can just list the folders and files of that folder with '-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1'

Comment: Using `-mindepth` is good, but don't use the wildcard version because it may fail if the maximum command argument size is exceeded.

Comment: `-mindepth` is nice, but I'd like to keep folders that have no subdirectories. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: There's at least one practical difference between `-mindepth 1` and adding `/*`. Mindepth matches top level dot files like `~/test/.env`, while /* will not. See example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28809662/490592

Answer (score 3):

Then you need `-type f` instead of `-type d`.

Or, if you want to display list of folders, excluding the parent `-mindepth 1` (`find ~/test -type d -mindepth 1`).

And now that you edited it, I think what you want may be

```
find ~/test -type d -mindepth 1 |cut -d/ -f3-
```

But I think you need to be more specific ;-)

Comment: ...then it would only list files. -type d is for directory. I'm simply trying to exclude the parent from it, As if I'm in the directory/

Comment: @cbcp, yes, I realized that I might have misread you (actually, was mostly basing my answer on example, not the prose). See the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed it with `sed`

```
find $BASE -type d \( ! -iname "." \)|sed s/$BASE//g
```

Where `$BASE` is initial foldername.

Comment: If any sub-directories (or files) happen to contain $BASE, sed will also remove that... Like in the given example...

Comment: even if you fixed your fault , sed would be overkill