# How to exclude this / current / dot folder from find "type d"

Tags: shell, directory, find

```
find . -type d
```

can be used to find all directories below some start point. But it returns the current directory (`.`) too, which may be undesired. How can it be excluded?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

[**POSIX 7 solution**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47):

```
find . ! -path . -type d
```

For this particular case (`.`), golfs better than the `mindepth` solution (24 vs 26 chars), although this is probably slightly harder to type because of the `!`.

To exclude other directories, this will golf less well and requires a variable for DRYness:

```
D="long_name"
find "$D" ! -path "$D" -type d
```

My decision tree between `!` and `-mindepth`:

- script? Use `!` for portability.
- interactive session on GNU?

  - exclude `.`? Throw a coin.
  - exclude `long_name`? Use `-mindepth`.

Comment: if you need to exclude multiple paths just do `find /path/ ! -path "/path/first" ! -path "/path/second"` is this only way?

Comment: @VincentDeSmet do you want to exclude just those paths, or actually not recurse into them? If just the paths, you can use `find / ! -regex '/\(a\|b\)/.*'` or more simply, pipe through grep. To not recurse, the above would be very inefficient and you should use `-prune`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Comment: my issue was as follows: I wanted to recursively delete everything within a directory except for 1 sub directory. I was using `find` with `grep` to exclude the directory but the parent directory was still there, causing everything to be deleted anyway.

Comment: @VincentDeSmet I don't see a direct solution with `find`, you'd need to check for prefixes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959317/bash-delete-all-files-and-directories-but-certain-ones But a Bash for loop can handle it :-)

Comment: You probably want to escape the exclamation char (`\!`) to be on the safe side. All the examples in my machine's `man find` have it escaped so it seems like it's probably a Good Idea™. Edit — Just noticed it even explicitly says: `! expr True if expr is false.  This character will also usually need protection from interpretation by the shell.`

Comment: @AdrianGünter yes, this brings me memories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125658/how-to-escape-history-expansion-exclamation-mark-inside-a-double-quoted-comm But for Bash (and POSIX?) I think it is not needed: `man bash` says: `! Start a history substitution, except when followed by a blank, newline, carriage return, =`. Otherwise we couldn't write things like `if ! true`.

Comment: @AdrianGünter I've looked at every POSIX occurrence of `!` but could not find anything that would expand in this case: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html I think history expansion does not exist there. So maybe it is better to leave as is? Maybe a crazy non-conforming implementation would give it another meaning when it is escaped? (but yes, Bash is non-conformant already for doing history expansions?)

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but for me, using this exact incantation still returns directories that begin with a dot, including the current dir.

Comment: @rbellamy the age of answers does not matter, and your comment is more than welcome. What we do need is your OS or `find` implementation name and version. I've just tested on Ubuntu 16.04, GNU findutils 4.7.0.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 - my bad - it does NOT include the current directory. It does return other dot-prefixed directories - but after reading the OP, I see that your answer only tries to exclude "current dir"?

Comment: `find . ! -name . -type d`

Answer (score 299):

Not only the recursion depth of `find` can be controlled by the `-maxdepth` parameter, the depth can also be limited from “top” using the corresponding `-mindepth` parameter. So what one actually needs is:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d
```

Comment: works on GNU find, but unfortunately is a gnu extension to the [POSIX 7 find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47), and even the LSB uses POSIX shell utilities (not the GNU extended ones)

Comment: This worked for me. Namely: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ...`

Answer (score 24):

I use `find ./* <...>` when I don't mind ignoring first-level dotfiles (the `*` glob doesn't match these by default in bash - see the 'dotglob' option in the shopt builtin: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).

```
eclipse tmp # find .
.
./screen
./screen/.testfile2
./.X11-unix
./.ICE-unix
./tmux-0
./tmux-0/default
```

```
eclipse tmp # find ./*
./screen
./screen/.testfile2
./tmux-0
./tmux-0/default
```

Comment: FYI. do not use this trick with `-exec`option. For example, if you try `find dir/* -type d -exec rmdir {} \;`, you will see errors.

Comment: You are mistaken, or perhaps misadvised. That command will work fine. If you are seeing errors, they will be coming from `rmdir` and are most likely telling you that the directories are not empty since `find` will do a depth-first search into the directories, showing the parents before their children.

Comment: Note: "ignoring first-level dotfiles" also means excluding all hidden files / directories.

Answer (score 7):

Well, a simple workaround as well (the solution was not working for me on windows git bash)

`find * -type d`

It might not be very performant, but gets the job done, and it's what we need sometimes.

[Edit] : As @AlexanderMills commented it will not show up hidden directories in the root location (eg `./.hidden`), but it will show hidden subdirectories (eg. `./folder/.hiddenSub`). [Tested with git bash on windows]

Comment: Use shopt -s dotglob before this, and you'll match every dotfile, except the one for the current folder.
Tested on both bash version 3.2 and 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to sed. Don't forget the -r that extend regular expression.

```
find . -type d | sed -r '/^\.$/d'
```