# Delete all files and directories but certain ones using Bash

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu, directory

I'm writing a script that needs to erase everything from a directory except two directories, mysql and temp.

I've tried this:

```
ls * | grep -v mysql | grep -v temp | xargs rm -rf
```

but this also keeps all the files that have mysql in their name, that i don't need. it also doesn't delete any other directories.

any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You may try:

```
rm -rf !(mysql|init)
```

Which is [POSIX defined](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/sh.1.asp#Parameter_Substitution):

```
 Glob patterns can also contain pattern lists. A pattern list is a sequence
of one or more patterns separated by either | or &. ... The following list
describes valid sub-patterns.

...
!(pattern-list):
    Matches any string that does not match the specified pattern-list.
...
```

**Note**: Please, take time to test it first!  Either create some test folder, or simply `echo` the parameter substitution, as duly noted by @mnagel:

```
echo !(mysql|init)
```

[*Adding useful information*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu): if the matching is not *active*, you may to enable/disable it by using:

```
shopt extglob                   # shows extglob status
shopt -s extglob                # enables extglob
shopt -u extglob                # disables extglob
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks! (definitely was testing somewhere else, don't wanna break things)

Comment: If this answers your question, mark the answer as accepted. It both allows others to know the question has been answered, as it means you acknowledge others effort to help you. To accept an answer, click on the tick mark, below the voting arrows.

Comment: for testing use `echo` as in `echo !(mysql|init)`

Comment: ok this works in the command line, but not in my script. Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: I'm sure this is worth another question! Would you mind to post it? -- I sincerely do not know a solution, but I'm still searching (:

Comment: > ok this works in the command line, but not in my script. Syntax error: "(" unexpected 

In a script, you need to explicitly enable extended globbing. Put this anywhere above the line: `shopt -s extglob` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Comment: @Motin Duly noted! I've added the information you pointed. Thanks for that!

Comment: note: this will not delete hidden directories like `.svn` or `.git` or simliar

Answer (score 6):

This is usually a job for `find`.  Try the following command (add `-rf` if you need a recursive delete):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! \( -name mysql -o -name temp \) -exec rm '{}' \;
```

(That is, find entries in `.` but not subdirectories that are not [named `mysql` or named `tmp`] and call `rm` on them.)

Comment: this also deletes the files inside the two folders

Comment: Not with the `maxdepth` option.  Remove the `-exec rm '{}' \;` to get a list of the matching files, which won't include anything below `./`.

Comment: This returns back `.` as well, so if you're executing `rm -Rf`, could potentially delete more than you intend...

Comment: Add -mindepth 1 to avoid deleting the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use find, ignore mysql and temp, and then rm -rf them.

```
find . ! -iname mysql ! -iname temp -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: this also deletes the files inside the two folders

Comment: To not delete everything inside these folders, use `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -iname mysql ! -iname temp -exec rm -rf {} \;`, or even better `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -iname mysql ! -iname temp -delete`

Comment: this in turn won't delete anything inside other subdirectories.