# Bash command runs in terminal but not in script file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to delete some files and folders from a directory. The command (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959317/bash-delete-all-files-and-directories-but-certain-ones)):

```
rm -rf !(file_i_don't_want_to_remove|other|other_one)
```

**Runs fine in terminal**, but if I try to use it inside a script (created using vim, 2 lines):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf !(one|two)
```

> ./file.sh: línea 2: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('

Translated:

> ./file.sh: line 2: syntax error near of unexpected element `('

Why?

PS. I've looked for other questions with the same name but they're all too specific for each script and seem not to be the same problem than mine.

Comment: Just a suggestion why don't you loop through all the files which you want to delete eg--> `.txt` or `.jpg` etc and delete them, just a suggestion.

Comment: Is the `bash` in your script as new as the one in your Terminal? You need to also set `shopt -s extglob` for that I think.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 may be recursive, more lines for no advantage IMHO.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've no idea at all. I've just found the command, tried it in my terminal and it worked, and then tried to use it in a script. I've never used `shopt` command nor know what does it do. Going to research a bit. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) extension enabled for this syntax to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /path/to/dir # See the comment below the answer
rm -rv !(one|two)
```

PS: Do **not** use `rm -f` in a script.

PS: If `/path/to/dir` is coming from a **variable**, make sure that is is **not empty** before using it with `cd`:

```
if [ -z "${path_to_delete}" ] ; then
    "path_to_delete is empty! Aborting"
    exit 1
fi
cd "${path_to_delete}"
rm -rv !(one|two)
```

Comment: And if you do `rm -r` in a file, **make sure you `cd` to the right directory first!** I have been bitten by that in the past. Thank $DIETY for tape backups

Comment: Incredibly good point! Also if `/path/to/dir` comes from a variable, make sure that it is not empty before using it in the `rm` command.

Comment: Maybe better to do `[ -z "${path_to_delete}" ] || [ ! -d "${path_to_delete}" ]` or just `cd "${path_to_delete}" || exit`

Comment: The `! -d` check can be a good idea depending on the situation, but note that `cd ""` will leave the working directory unchanged and return `0`