# ubuntu bash parallel process finished with success but terminal "frozen"

Tags: bash, find, 7zip, gnu-parallel

I have this script that compress every directory into separate files:

```
#!/bin/bash

#compress every subfolder into separate files
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | parallel -0 --eta 7z a -t7z -bso0 -bsp0 -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -ms=on -mmt=on {}.7z {}
```

Which works as intended, but at the end, the terminal stays at:

```
Computers / CPU cores / Max jobs to run
1:local / 8 / 8

Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
ETA: 0s Left: 1 AVG: 0.51s  local:1/344/100%/0.5s
```

I have to `ctrl+c` to exit and recover the terminal. Is that normal or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If you run your `find` command without piping the output into **GNU Parallel**, you will see you are also compressing the current directory into which you are writing the compressed files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks!, how do I fix it?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17389439/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @MarkSetchell, the problem was that find prints the current directory too. To avoid that, I used `-mindepth 1` as an aditional option for `find`.

Comment: Well done! Thank you for sharing your findings.