# Copy directories and their sub directories created day ago

Tags: copy

I tried to copy Copy directories and their subdirectories created a day ago as follows:

```
find /application/work/   -type d -mtime -1  -exec cp -r {} /tmp/backup \;
```

But it is copying all directories (Not only the ones created a day ago).

Would you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is also finding the working directory `/application/work/` and is copying it, see [How to exclude this / current / dot folder from find "type d"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525004/how-to-exclude-this-current-dot-folder-from-find-type-d). Since you're executing `cp -r`, it recursively copies everything in `.` before also copying the subset of directories you've found via `-mtime`. You need to set the `-mindepth` to exclude the working directory from the paths on which `find` will operate.

Modify your command to:

```
find /application/work -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime -1 -exec cp -r {} /tmp/backup \;
```